# Fill datagridview value to the constructor

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

This is my constructor,

```
new VisConfig(
string.Empty,
string.Empty,
new List<SensorConfig>()
    {

        new SensorConfig(
        string.Empty, //DGV COl0
        string.Empty, //DGV COl1
        new List<CoveredTrafficLane>()
            {
                new CoveredLane(string.Empty) //DGV COl 2,3,4,5
            },
                new RseDevicePosition(
                new ValueWithUnit<int>(0, "mm"), //DGV COl6
                new ValueWithUnit<int>(0, "mm"), //DGV COl7
                new ValueWithUnit<int>(0, "mm"), //DGV COl8
                new ValueWithUnit<int>(0, "tenthOfDegree"), //DGV COl9
                new ValueWithUnit<int>(0, "tenthOfDegree"), //DGV COl10
                new ValueWithUnit<int>(0, "tenthOfDegree")), //DGV COl11
                0, //DGV COl12
                0) //DGV COl13
    },
```

I'm trying to get the data from the DGV(winform) to this constructor.

Plase help me, how can i get the datagridvalue and fill it to the constructor.

Comment: Can you put everything in the selected DataRow into a list container or just pass the DataRow in?

Comment: @Bmo: Could you show me, how can i pass the datarow in?? Thank u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right your question -> your constructor of DtuSensorConfig take data from one row of DataGridView.
So create List outside of VisConfig constructor and then pass this list there.

```
List<DtuSensorConfig> dSensorConf = new List<DtuSensorConfig>()
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView3.Rows)
{
    //Create a CoveredTrafficLane list 
    List<CoveredTrafficLane> covTrafLane = new List<CoveredTrafficLane>();
    //DGV COl 2,3,4,5
    covTrafLane.Add(New CoveredTrafficLane(dr.Cells["DGVCOL2"].Value.ToString()));
    covTrafLane.Add(New CoveredTrafficLane(dr.Cells["DGVCOL3"].Value.ToString()));
    covTrafLane.Add(New CoveredTrafficLane(dr.Cells["DGVCOL4"].Value.ToString()));
    covTrafLane.Add(New CoveredTrafficLane(dr.Cells["DGVCOL5"].Value.ToString()));

    //Create RseDevicePosition
    RseDevicePosition devPos;
    int ctx = 0;
    Int32.TryParse(dr.Cells["dtux"].Value.ToString(), out ctx);
    int cty = 0;
    Int32.TryParse(dr.Cells["dtuy"].Value.ToString(), out cty);
    int ctz = 0;
    Int32.TryParse(dr.Cells["dtuz"].Value.ToString(), out ctz);
    int dtuazu = 0;
    Int32.TryParse(dr.Cells["dtuazim"].Value.ToString(), out dtuazu);
    int dtuele = 0;
    Int32.TryParse(dr.Cells["dtuele"].Value.ToString(), out dtuele);
    int dtuti = 0;
    Int32.TryParse(dr.Cells["dtutilt"].Value.ToString(), out dtuti);

    devPos = new RseDevicePosition(
    new ValueWithUnit<int>(ctx, "mm"),
    new ValueWithUnit<int>(cty, "mm"),
    new ValueWithUnit<int>(ctz, "mm"),
    new ValueWithUnit<int>(dtuazu, "tenthOfDegree"),
    new ValueWithUnit<int>(dtuele, "tenthOfDegree"),
    new ValueWithUnit<int>(dtuti, "tenthOfDegree"));

    //here create a DtuSensorConfig
    dSensorConf.Add(
        new DtuSensorConfig(dr.Cells["DGVCOL0"].Value.Tostring(), //DGV COl0
                            dr.Cells["DGVCOL1"].Value.Tostring(), //DGV COl1       
                            covTrafLane,
                            devPos));
}
VisConfig vConf = new VisConfig(string.Empty,
                                string.Empty,
                                dSensorConf); //
```

Comment: `DataGridViewColumn col in dr.Columns`this line is not correct and if i use like this `foreach(DataGridViewColumn col in dr.Cells)` i got a  problem. Invalid Cast Excetion was unhandled...

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I think here you can use foreach(DataGridViewColumn in dataGridView3.Columns). And when you loopin Columns you need only 4 columns(so maybe ForNext better if columnIndex doesn't change)

Comment: Forget last comment :) This I think better solution to that problem: Because you know exactly what columns goes to CoveredTrafficLane's list write without looping covTrafLane.Add(dr.Cells(DGVCOL2).Value.ToString(); covTrafLane.Add(dr.Cells(DGVCOL3).Value.ToString(); and so ....

Comment: I'm getting null reference error. and by the above method it's not working.

Comment: I updated answer, for me it's can work. But for Null Expression can you gve somemore code or examples. Sorry I am working more with VB.NET so syntax can be from there :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, as I got into coding it. I realize this my not be ideal.

You would need to set the selection property of the DGV to entire row. Or if that does not fit your spec you might have to tweak the collection it loops over in the second loop.

```
    private void btnMyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgvMyGrid.Columns)
            dt.Columns.Add(col.Name.ToString());

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dgvMyGrid.SelectedRows[0].Cells)
            dr[cell.OwningColumn.Name] = cell.Value.ToString();               

    }
```

When this is done the "dr" variable is a dataRow that represents the selection from the dgv. You can set up your constructor to take an argument of type DataRow.

Then you should be able to use DataRow.Cells[] similar to how you've posted you know how to do, to get your values.

No warranty implied here, it was working better in my brain. Good luck.